# How can i put my JSONArray data into LinkedHashMap in android?

Tags: android

I want to put my JSONArray data into LinkedHashMap.
I have JSONArray namely batting_order which i need to put in LinkedHashMap with key and value.

Here, is my json data

```
{
"batting_order": [
[
"b",
"1"
],
[
"a",
"1"
]
]
}
```

Please, Help me to solve out this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this code help you.. hare i ve shown how to make a json string using `JSONObject` and just put it in `LinkedHashMap`... jsonData returns a json string

```
JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject();
    ArrayList<String> array=new ArrayList<>();
    array.add("a");
    array.add("1");

    try{
        jsonData .put("bating_order",array);
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
    LinkedHashMap<String,JSONObject> map=new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("your_key",jsonData );
```

for any problem .. comment please ..